# How to fail T-SQL script without using RAISERROR()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

Check if database is read-only in first step of SQL Server Agent job. If this is the case - exit the job.

So I figured I will use Advanced Properties for Job Step and select "Quit the job reporting success" for "On failure cation:"

But how does one fail T-SQL script without using RAISERROR()? Reason I don't want to use RAISERROR() is because one needs to be a member of sysadmin server role to use it.

I found rather ugly approach that works - selecting something from the table that doesn't exist, script looks like this:

```
declare @DBIsRO int;

SET @DBIsRO= (SELECT is_read_only
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'test')

IF @DBIsRO=1 
   select * from dd -- table dd doesn't exist in current database
```

However, this just seems like a kludge and I am looking for a 'proper' approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reread documentation:

> Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user.
>   Severity levels from 19 through 25 can only be specified by members of
>   the sysadmin ...

You can do:

```
raiserror( 'Readonly',16,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reason I don't want to use RAISERROR() is because one needs to be a member of sysadmin server role to use it.

Well if that would be true nobody would ever use it. Is simply not true. The [spec says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

> Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user.
>   Severity levels from 19 through 25 can only be specified by members of
>   the sysadmin fixed server role or users with ALTER TRACE permissions.

Even if that would be true, you could use [code signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to leverage it. But is simply not necessary.